# android Firebase query- reference to (pushid )?

Tags: android, firebase, reference, push

Please help
this is my firebase structure

[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc2cP.png)

following query is working fine but i have to hardcode the push id "MZgPRv6xKK5isnnPTLn"  ,  i dont want  to hard code the value highlighted below from following query is there a way to get this reference of this push key ? to be used for query so that i can replace the "MZgPRv6xKK5isnnPTLn"

[push id hard coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn7Cp.png)

```
 Query lastQuery = dbr1.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child("-MZgPRv6xKK5isnnPTLn").child("sms").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
            lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dns) {
                   
                    for (DataSnapshot chl : dns.getChildren())
                    {
                        Log.d("read_last_nodes", String.valueOf(dns.child("no").getValue()));
                        
                    }
            }
}
```

Follows is the code of writing into Firebase

```
path= dbref_1.child("users").child(mAuth.getUid()).push().getKey();

dbref_1.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(path)
.child("sms").child("SMS_no_" + i).child("no").setValue(no);
```

Comment: To understand better, you need to get all SMS objects that exist within all pushed IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'getKey()' to get any key in firebase database. In your case to get the key you have to point to the hardcoded key, and then use getKey on the returned snapshot. After getting the key you can proceed to run your query.

```
            DatabaseReference ref = dbr1.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dns) {
                        if(dns.exists) {
                           String key = dns.getKey();
                           Query lastQuery = dns.child(key).child("sms").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
                          ///rest of query logic
                        }
                    }
         }
```

Comment: thanks , i have got another problem now my data is more than 100 records and when i run this query its only showing 100th record , how i can get the 650th records which is the last record in my list ?

Comment: If my answer is correct mark it as such. Limit to last shows the last record regardless of the number of records you have.

Comment: Note also the records are ordered by key first, and then the last one retrieved, that may account for the discrepancy.